# How can i seperate/split part of string messege in node red

Tags: json, string, message, node-red

I received this message:

```
 "data: "{"cmd":"gw","seqno":515816,"EUI":"000DB53113683569","ts":1510584501221,"fcnt":1,"port":2,"freq":868100000,"toa":1482,"dr":"SF12 BW125 4/5","ack":false,"gws":[{"rssi":-71,"snr":9.5,"ts":1510584501221,"time":"2017-11-13T14:48:21.218869Z","gweui":"B827EBFFFF6A14DD","lat":50.0751806,"lon":14.4022641}],"bat":255,"data":"0002560000000000000000"}""
```

I need to put away the "data: " and on the end the "

I need just the JSON message if I use JSON node it just writes me an error because of the "data: "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function node to chop the string up. Something like this:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.substring(7,msg.payload.length - 1);
return msg;
```

And then wire this to a JSON node.

Comment: msg.payload = msg.payload.substring(8,msg.payload.length - 4); 
I just made little change but it works :)
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could add the missing  `{}` and then JSON.parse.

```
var string = "{" + msg.payload +"}"
var dataObject = JSON.parse(string)

msg.payload = dataObject.data
return msg
```